# How to Render Camera Preview onto SurfaceTexture (openGL) with WebRTC on Android

Tags: android, webrtc

With **WebRTC** on Android, does anyone have an idea how I can render the camera preview onto a `SurfaceTexture`? any examples will be welcome!